# SQLite Database not adding information to database and not returning errors in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have made a login and register system I am making and the login system works fine but when I try to use this register part it will go through the code and it will not result in an error it will just not add the information but everything runs and the boolean isRegister below also returns try even tho it don't add to the sqlite database. I also get the Message Dialog saying Account Created Successfully! but it still doesn't add the information to the database.

```
public boolean isRegister(String fname, String lname, String email, String password, String studentNum, String grade, String division) throws Exception
{
    PreparedStatement pr = null;

    try
    {
        String sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, studentNum, grade, division) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        pr = connection.prepareStatement(sql1);
        pr.setString(1, lname + " " + fname);
        pr.setString(2, email);
        pr.setString(3, password);
        pr.setString(4, studentNum);
        pr.setString(5, grade);
        pr.setString(6, division);
        pr.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Created Successfully!");

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will not add the information to the Database and the code that calls this class is as follows

```
LoginModel loginmodel = new LoginModel();

if (loginmodel.isRegister(fname, lname, email_in.getText(), password, studentNum, grade_in.getValue().toString(), division))
{
    new login().setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}
```

If you need any further information just ask.

Comment: It would be good if you put the structure of your table, maybe it could be due to typing errors of attribute names or data types

Comment: Make inquiries so you can know if it is a matter of the connection or unsupported libraries, because if it receives information then it is that it is doing the insertion badly and if it does not receive any information when making the query it is that your connection is not well

Comment: I used my sql manager and it is able to insert properly so i don't think it is the internet connection I also didn't spell it wrong either i just checked

Comment: Try `executeUpdate()` instead of `execute()`. `executeUpdate()` returns also the number of inserted rows.

Comment: I FOUND THE ANSWER CHANGE THE `.execute()` to `.executeUpdate()` and change the sql query to `INSERT INTO 'users' ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'studentNum', 'grade', 'division') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` This is for anyone else having trouble with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not ever write a catch block like this. Exceptions contain 4 useful bits of information (the exception type, the message, the stack trace, and the causal chain). Also, in general if an exception occurs, the 'state' that the process your code is running through is in, is no longer valid, and thus it should be aborted. You throw away 3 of the 4 useful things, print the remaining bit to a black hole that your IDE and logging tools can not interact with, and then let the flow continue. Just add `throws WhateverYouNeed` to your method signatures and if truly that is not an option, and you have *no idea* what to do with the exception, the fallback is this: `catch (ExceptionICannotHandle e) { throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e); }`. Then you'd see more / better error messaging here. Note that your method sig ALREADY has `throws Exception` in it, so your catch block here is just writing code to make your app run worse. Just delete those 7 lines of code. Hey, deleting code whilst it becomes better, that's gotta feel good, right!
2. Unless your db connection is in auto-commit mode, you still need to commit after your `execute()` call.
3. If this code throws, it'll return false. Did you check for this? Do you get the message dialog with `Account Created Successfully!`, or not? That seems like pertinent information here.

Comment: I do indeed get the Account Created Successfully and I did change the exception to throw a SQLException in that catch block and I removed the throws Exception at the top but it still doesn't return anything and doesn't go the sql database! I also set it to autoCommit when it astablises the connection and no luck!

Comment: Sounds like it's _NOT_ in autocommit mode, or it's writing to a different DB than you are querying.